# Why does co_argcount return 2, instead of 4?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the following function, there are four parameters `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`.

```
def f(a, b = 10, *c, **d):
    return (a, b, c, d)
```

But, when I log the `co_argcount` attribute of this function's code object, I get `2` returned.

```
>>> f.__code__.co_argcount
2
>>> f.__code__.co_nlocals
4
```

Why is this so? Shouldn't `co_argcount` return `4` since the function has four parameters.

Why are `c` and `d` referred to as local variables, not parameters?

Comment: As per the docs ["number of arguments *(not including keyword only arguments, ``*`` or ``**`` args)*"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Returns the number of positional arguments (including arguments with
> default values).

https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/code/argcount.html

> Returns the number of local variables used by the function (including
> arguments).

https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/code/nlocals.html

so in your case only two positional parameters ( a and b )

while there are for local variables a,b,c,d

**Output of nlocal if we define a extra local variable:**

[image]

official link : https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html

Comment: You might want to link to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html)

Answer (score 2):

From [3.2 The standart type hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=co_argcount#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

> Special read-only attributes: `co_name` gives the function name; `co_argcount` is **the total number of positional arguments (including positional-only arguments and arguments with default values)**;
>
> [...]
> The following flag bits are defined for `co_flags`: bit `0x04` is set if the function uses the `*arguments` syntax to accept an arbitrary number of positional arguments; bit `0x08` is set if the function uses the `**keywords` syntax to accept arbitrary keyword arguments;

`0x04` flag is denoted `VARARGS`

`0x08` flag is denoted `VARKEYWORDS`

This and the rest can be seen using the function `dis.show_code`

```py
>>> import dis
>>> def f(a, b = 10, *c, **d):
...     return (a, b, c, d)
... 
>>> dis.show_code(f)
Name:              f
Filename:          <stdin>
Argument count:    2
Positional-only arguments: 0
Kw-only arguments: 0
Number of locals:  4
Stack size:        4
Flags:             OPTIMIZED, NEWLOCALS, VARARGS, VARKEYWORDS, NOFREE
Constants:
   0: None
Variable names:
   0: a
   1: b
   2: c
   3: d
```